# Image not showing when linked into <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

```
window.onload = function(){
        var filepaths = paths.split(",");
        var folder = filepaths[1].split("/");
        var appendable = folder[0];
        createList(appendable, filepaths);

        function createList(divname, paths){
        var ulist = document.createElement("ul");
        ulist.id = "sb-slider";
        ulist.className = "sb-slider";
        var appended = document.getElementById(divname);
        appended.appendChild(ulist);
            for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++){
                var lilist = document.createElement("li");
                ulist.appendChild(lilist);
                var image = document.createElement("img");
                image.src = paths[i] ;
                lilist.appendChild(image);
                }
            }
            $('#sb-slider').slicebox();
        }
```

This is the Javascript part.

```
<div id="pluginAppObj_01">

<script></script>
<ul id="sb-slider" class="sb-slider">
    <li>
        <img src="pluginAppObj_01/1.jpg"></img>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="pluginAppObj_01/2.jpg"></img>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="pluginAppObj_01/3.jpg"></img>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And this is the HTML part.

Basically if I try to add the  with document.write, the images show.

At the moment, by checking the code from the browser, the ul appears to have no height and no images are visible.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

divname contains the name of the div where to append the element, and paths contains the paths for each image.

Comment: where is `paths` declared as you may have problems as you use it in your `window.onload` and then declare it as a local variable in your `createList` function

Comment: Yup has to be a path issue.

Comment: Are you sure it is a path issue even though in the html ouput it shows correctly? <img src="pluginAppObj_01/3.jpg"></img>. If I hover over the image path inside the src it also shows the image, saying that the current dimension is 0x0

Comment: add pluginAppObj_01/3.jpg to your page url and see whether you get the image? Might be permission also, but it has something to do with reading from the image source.

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8080/index.html/pluginAppObj_01/3.jpg, if I actually go like this, it won't show

Comment: It should be http://127.0.0.1:8080/pluginAppObj_01/3.jpg , but where are the images? it's localhost so images don't seem to be in the root (www, html or whatever it is called)

Comment: 127.0.0.1:8080/pluginAppObj_01/3.jpg, yes like this it will show. I am using a software with website preview. It generates a preview folder with the html in it, and then a folder called pluginappobj with the images inside

Comment: if image in the link shows it should show in the page too, weird. If the plugin adds the images in a folder, then try add that folder name to your path: Like: `src="./pluginappobj/pluginAppObj_01/3.jpg"`

Comment: I keep on recieving the 200 OK message in the network section, and the image is uploaded and recognized, but still not showing... I really have no idea why is that :o